# How to validate date with Moment.js to a specified format?

Tags: javascript, validation, date, momentjs

I am unable to find an existing question/answer on how to validate a date input using moment.js to ensure that it is in this format, "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z".

Given that I've got a date as a string, "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z", how can validate that the date string is strictly in the format specified, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ".

I've tried the following and it does not seem to work for me.

```js
var dateTime = "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z";
var utc = moment(dateTime, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ", true)
var isUTC = utc.isValid(dateTime);

console.log(isUTC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Could anyone please provide a couple of examples?

Thanks in advance
-R

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet shows it works fine. The issue was with `const moment = require('moment')`

Comment: I thought it should return true, rather. Unless my format specification is invalid?

Comment: Please use uppercase `HH` for 0-23 hours, lowercase `hh` is for 01-12.

Comment: Sorry I can't find the edit button for my question. Here is how I have tried after @vincenzoc's suggestion: var validDateUTC = (dateTime) => {    
   const DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SSZ";
   const DATE_LENGTH = 20;
   var isUTC = false;
   if (dateTime.length===DATE_LENGTH) {
      const moment = require('moment');
      var utc = moment(dateTime, DATE_FORMAT, true);
      isUTC = utc.isValid(dateTime);
   }    

   return isUTC;
};

Comment: To test the function above I have some code in Chai: describe('UTC date time validation', () => { 
    it('should be a valid date', () => {
        const dateTime = "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z";
        assert.isTrue(validation.validDateUTC(dateTime));        
    });   
}); // It seems to work now but I am not sure if it is valid???

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have changed the time format to HH:mm:ss and it works fine. Works also for a negative test case:     it('should be an invalid date', () => {
        const dateTime = "2017-12-31T23:59:65Z";
        assert.isFalse(validation.validDateUTC(dateTime));
    });

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moment tokens are case sensitive, you should use uppercase `HH` to parse `0-23` hours, `hh` is for parsing `1-12`. See [`moment(String, String, Boolean)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs.

Here a live example:

```js
var dateTime = "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z";
var utc = moment(dateTime, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ", true)
var isUTC = utc.isValid();
console.log(isUTC);

utc = moment(dateTime, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ", true)
isUTC = utc.isValid();
console.log(isUTC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! that works fine for me. Just stumbled on hh and HH.