# How to validate 2020-12-31T13:00:00.000Z using moment js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, momentjs

I would like to validate this date 2020-12-31T13:00:00.000Z but I couldn't find a method in moment that does the job . Kindly help

Comment: what do you mean validate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse ISO 8601 into date and time format using Moment js in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735724/how-to-parse-iso-8601-into-date-and-time-format-using-moment-js-in-javascript)

Comment: See [\[javascript\]\[momentjs\] how to validate a date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bmomentjs%5D+how+to+validate+a+date) and [How to validate date with Moment.js to a specified format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598667/how-to-validate-date-with-moment-js-to-a-specified-format?r=SearchResults&s=1|108.5944)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `isValid()`.

```js
    console.log(moment("2020-12-31T13:00:00.000Z").isValid());
```

`true` is returned.

```js
    console.log(moment("2020-12-32T13:00:00.000Z").isValid());
```

`false` is returned.

Comment: If the intention is to validate the values and the format, the format should be supplied and strict flag should be set, otherwise *any* string that either moment.js or the built–in parser converts to a valid Date will be considered "valid", e.g. in some browsers, "foo 2020" is a valid date, not in others.